# Infection in a group of 100 people

Tags: combinatorics

In a groupof 100 people, one person went on a trip and returned to the group after catching COVID-19. We know that each person in the group can infect 3 people at most, and everyone in the group will be infected. According to this, at most how many people in this group are only infected? That is, find the maximum number of people that catch the virus but do not infect anyone.

I solved it like this. Case 1 infects 3 people and they infect 9 people and they infect 27 people. From these 27 person 7 remains only infected and 20 of them infect remaining 60 people. So the maximum number is 67. I want to prove that the answer cannot be 68. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can do your calculations backwards: $99$ are infected by others, so if $N$ are only infected by others and $100-N$ infect others, then $99 \le 3(100-N)$ giving  $N\le 67$